# How can I get the function of a event (debuging jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

for example I have:

```
<a href="" id="#activador">asdasd</a>
```

```
...
//js code in other place or other file hard to find, I have this:
$('#activador').click(simplefunction);       or
$(document).on('click','#activador',simplefunction);     or
$('#activador').live('click',simplefunction);

function simplefunction(){
alert('hello');
}
...
```

How can I find if the html `('#activador')` have a function attached, and how can I find what function the element `('#activador')` will trigger?

I know using

```
var clickEvents = $('#activador').data("events").click;
```

but I cannot use something like this:

```
var clickEvents = $('#activador').data("events").on; or 
var clickEvents = $('#activador').data("events").live;
```

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure what's being asked here since `.click` will give you the function even if you use `on`.

Comment: does not appears, when is .on('click','#activador',simplefunction); and I use: clickEvents = $('#activador').data("events").click;
appear Cannot read property 'click' of undefined  on chrome
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use _data function to find out event associated with that element,

```
console.log($._data($('#activador'), "events").click);
```

Comment: thanks, I have put that code but appears:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined 
(anonymous function) 

only can I get the functions attached when I use: $('#activador').click(simplefunction); and  var clickEvents = $('#activator').data("events").click; but with 'on' or live appears the same error

Comment: @dexter00x which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: 1.7.1, do you think that should to use the latest version to do work that?

Comment: I have test with 1.10.1 but the same,
using console.log($._data($('#activador')[0], "events").click); works only with:
$('#activador').click(simplefunction);
but not with:
$(document).on('click','#activador',simplefunction);     or
$('#activador').live('click',simplefunction);

Comment: live function is actually deprecated in jQuery use bind instead

Comment: ok thanks, now still I cannot get the functions attached with 'on' please,

Comment: This is might what you want,
    $._data( $("#activador")[0], "events" )